# Config Error on different iis version?

Tags: iis, web, webforms

I am getting the this error message

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Module: IIS Web Core 
Notification: Unknown 
Handler: Not yet determined 
Error Code: 0x800700b7
Config Error There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined
```

I have migrated a site from one server(iis6) to another(iis7) and when running on the new server I get the error in question. I cant seem to find a solution to this anywhere? Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Which version of .net framework are you trying to use on the new server with your site? Is it the same used on the old server?

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove this question I found an answer which solved it for me, it turns out it nothing to do with iis. For anyone else reading this go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387322/iis7-deployment-duplicate-system-web-extensions-scripting-scriptresourcehandl. The third answer down did it for me