# There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis-7, frameworks

i have 2 servers and i've to migrate the website to one 2003 server to 2008 server.
When i try to run the website in the 2008 server i have this error:
There is a duplicate `system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler` section defined

But i don't have a duplicate '`system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler` in the `web.config`. And when i delete this line then it complains about a duplicate of the next line, and so on until I remove almost all of the config sections.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!--DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN.DMS.BEGIN. -->
    <section name="EventListeners" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler,System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="policyInjection" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.Configuration.PolicyInjectionSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
    <!--DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END.DMS.END. -->
    <!-- enables ASP.NET AJAX extensions -->
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="Config">
      <section name="SQLServer" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="Remoting" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="General" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="Pagination" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="ProxyServer" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="ERPWebServices" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="Licencing" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="SaaS" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="IISConfiguration" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
      <section name="OtherInformation" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,system, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, Custom=null" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

Comment: There must be a duplicate somewhere, not necessarily in the same web.config file. The duplicate can be in another web.config file at different folder level, or in some case in [machine.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387322/iis7-deployment-duplicate-system-web-extensions-scripting-scriptresourcehandl?rq=1). For workaround, try adding `<remove name="scriptResourceHandler"/>` before `<section name="scriptResourceHandler" .../>`

Comment: Hi, when i do this then it complains about the next line:There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices/jsonSerialization' section defined

Comment: add `<remove name="...">` elements for every `<section>` complained

Comment: After the final one appears that:


Runtime Error 
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: Have you changed the appPoll to version 2 instead of version 4?

Comment: Hello, yes i have and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when the web site I was trying to setup and get running was supposed to be setup to run under .net 2.0/3.5 but I had it setup to run under .NET 4.0 by accident.

Background:

Per comment under the original issue "There must be a duplicate somewhere, not necessarily in the same web.config file. The duplicate can be in another web.config file at different folder level, or in some case in machine.config."  I did find the duplicate.
In the .net 4.0 machine.config, entries were there which duplicated the contents of my web.config, which resulted in the duplicate error.  However, the .net 2.0 machine.config did not have duplicates with my web.config.

Switching the application pool to run .net 2.0, as it should have been in the first place, eliminated the error.